# Data copied from NTFS drive to ext3 drive disappears upon reboot in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, ntfs, ext3

I am trying to copy 500+ GB's of data from an NTFS formatted HDD to a ext3 formatted one. I am doing so from within Windows 7 Pro 64.

At first I was using `Ext2` Volume Manager to mount the `ext3` drive.

But after copying all of the files and rebooting, I discovered that all of the files were missing from the target drive. The target drive had gone back to only containing the files that it had *before* the copy job.

After a bit of mucking around, I uninstalled `Ext2` Volume Manager and replaced it with the 10-day trial version of Paragon ExtFS for Windows.

Unbelievably, the situation remains the same. Any files that are copied from the source to the target HDD are **missing after reboot!**

(I don't have a Linux PC available, but I also tried booting off of a Ubuntu 16.01 Live USB drive to carry out this task. But I found the copying speed, from both Unity and from the terminal, to be unbearably slow... <2MB/s.)

How is this even possible?! What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to make this work?!

Comment: Did you run `fsck -f`just to make sure?

Comment: I'm copying the files in a W7 environment, so that isn't possible. I suppose I could run `chkdsk` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ext2explore](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/?source=typ_redirect) to move your data then unmount the drive before rebooting.

Comment: Thank you. I am experimenting with your suggesting right now.

My mind is still blown that it should be necessary to unmount the disk though. I would have thought that, if the files were written, they are written.

Perhaps that is why @Eugen Rieck recommended checking the file system above.

Comment: Unmounting the drive seems to be the trick... thank you @GAD3R.

Comment: I'm still really curious as to why unmounting before reboot is necessary. 

I suppose the file system is updated somehow to take note of the changes.

I also find it odd that both **Ext2 Volume Manager** *and* **ExtFS for Windows** do not attempt to make it explicitly clear for newcomers like myself that this is necessary in (some? all?) cases.

I told myself that my lost hours are because I didn't RTFM, but just now I've gone back and read all available documentation for both utilities—which amounts to almost nothing—and this scenario is not mentioned. Oh well.